# MVC3, switching between Views in the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on a MVC project that is supposed to have one page only, with two zones. On one zone I have a Google Map with markers, and the second zone is populated with the selected marker's details.

The **details** view has a button that when clicked should change the entire view into **edit** mode without refreshing the page or redirecting it. I have used two views, for **details** and **edit** and with the help of `ajaxForm` function I am switching back and forth between these two views. I'm adding the `ajaxForm` on `documentready` for **edit** view.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#currentDiv').ajaxForm(function(data) { 
            $('#currentDiv').html(data);
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

The problem appears when on server-side an error appears while trying to save data from **edit** view and I want to return to the same **edit** view with the errors displayed. The `ajaxForm` handler is not added any more and even if the new values that will try to be saved are ok, the **detail** view is loaded in another page.

Unfortunately, the use of `ajaxForm` creates some other problems because I don't have control over the cases when the ajax call fails.

Any ideas on how could I fix this? Is it some other solution to switch between those two views without using ajaxForm and without refreshing the page?

Comment: Can you show the controller code that is throwing the server side error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a couple of different questions that you are asking.

First off, you add jquery handlers to deal with the case when you get a 500 type error from the server.

Something like the following.  I suggest taking a look at the docs for more info.

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event,jqXHR,ajaxSettings,thrownError){
   if (jqXHR.status != 0){
         window.location = <error page>
    }
}
```

The second problem seems to stem around error handling of known errors (say invalid input).  In this case I suggest the following workflow.

1)  User clicks on edit button, taken to edit screen 
2)  User enters in data, use client side validation to do initial check 
3)  User submits, user is then taken to the view screen and is shown a
    success or error message.

The server response could look like:

```
public ActionResult Edit(EditModel model){
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     return Json(new {successful = false, message = "Failed.."});
   }
   ...
}
```

On the client side, your form callback should now handle the message and the fact it was successful or not.  In my implementation, I used knockoutjs to create a "message" area that I could update and clear. (I created templates, etc).

Remember to use client side validation for the easy field validation stuff....  This will save a trip back to the server.

Yours could be quite simple, by popping up the message returned from the server.

Lastly, document ready only fires when the original document is done loading, never again for an ajax call (at least that is my understanding).  Just put that code that is the document.ready at the bottom of the edit page.  It will fire after the html it is targeting has already been rendered.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I have begun to move away from the asp.net views available in ASP.Net MVC due to some incompatibilities and/or unnecessary complexities when trying to achieve functionalities expected of AJAX enabled sites of the day.

I would recommend moving towards a design where you use "dumb" HTML files, use jQuery to download them using AJAX and drop them into a container (personally I use a div) and then use another AJAX call to gather the data from a controller. There are a number of advantages to this approach:

1. It establishes a real (not fake) separation between client side and server side code.
2. Html files can be cached on the client cutting down on the amount of data transmitted.
3. Binding of the Html elements becomes a client side task achieved using jQuery offloading processing cycles from the server.
4. Controllers essentially become collections of web methods which means they can be untilized by iPhone and Android apps making mobile deployment easier.

I realize this probably isn't the exact answer you're looking for and this may not be an option for you but my hope is that it will help someone at some point make a decision to move away from mixing HTML and server side code.

Comment: I totally agree.  I have really moved to passing json data to the views and letting the js take care of the rest.  Seems like a better model.